# Run each element of Python list as code in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, list, jupyter

I have a list of strings which if executed store the api call value to response variables. I'd like to execute each element of the list as a command in order to store the api value as different response variables. But I'd like to do this without manually copying and pasting the output of my 'for' command.

```
mySuperCoolList=['response1=requests.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/EBND/quote")',
     'response2=requests.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/EMB/quote")',
     'response3=requests.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/XOMA/quote")',
     'response4=requests.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/TUSK/quote")',
     'response5=requests.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/CQH/quote")',
     'response6=requests.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/DMLP/quote")']
```

What I do at present is run:

```
    for i in mySuperCoolList:  
           print(i)
```

Then I copy the output of that command in jupyter notebook and paste it into the next cell and run the commands to store the data into the respective response numbers.

What I'd like to do is hit 'shift-enter' on some code with respect to this list and have each element of the list run. How can I cut out the manual copy and paste to the next line?

Comment: Perhaps the `requests` python library will help you? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: I think it could, but I still want to know how to do the crazy thing I'm trying to do. It seems super basic - run elements of lists as commands.

Comment: replace `print()` with `eval()`?

Comment: @code11 why are you suggesting `eval` as a solution?

Comment: `I'd like to execute each element of the list as a command`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > What I'd like to do is hit 'shift-enter' on some code with respect to this list and have each element of the list run.

Without going into is it really wise to go about this in this manner, direct answer to your question goes like this (rules separate cells for better visibility of what is happening):

---

```
import requests
```

---

```
mySuperCoolList=['response1=requests.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/EBND/quote")',
     'response2=requests.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/EMB/quote")',
     'response3=requests.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/XOMA/quote")',
     'response4=requests.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/TUSK/quote")',
     'response5=requests.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/CQH/quote")',
     'response6=requests.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/DMLP/quote")']
```

---

```
for i in mySuperCoolList:
           get_ipython().run_cell(i)
```

---

```
print(response1)
# ...
print(response6)
```

Now, having said this, although you can get your result directly manipulating underlying structure (run_cell, set_next_input, etc...) it is really better to use requests package directly as suggested in comments if nothing else then to be able to run it as regular python script without much fuss later on...

Also worth mentioning is that unless for some reason you keep tabs on exactly those 6 requests in your awesome list and you absolutely never, ever want to expand or contract that list, variable naming `response1..6` suggest you might want to put those in some decent structure such as array or list. Just saying...

Comment: Thank you so much - you rule. I will definitely explore the better form that you suggest.

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you, keep going! If I may trouble you also to accept and upvote answer in line with [this SO policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks!